# Как удалить файл в Laravel AWS s3

Tags: laravel, laravel7

В контроллере написано так:

```
    // Тут делаем валидацию
    $request->validate([
        "image" => "required|image",
        "gif_image" => "required|image",
        // тут много валидации ...
    ]);

    // Тут добавляем картинки в aws
    $path = $request->file("image")->store("images", "s3");
    $gif = $request->file("gif_image")->store("gif_images", "s3");

    // Публичный доступ для картинок
    Storage::disk("s3")->setVisibility($path, 'public');
    Storage::disk("s3")->setVisibility($gif, 'public');

    // Создаем наш элемент
    ModelName::create([
        "image" => basename($path),
        "image_url" => Storage::disk("s3")->url($path),
        "gif_image" => basename($gif),
        "gif_image_url" => Storage::disk("s3")->url($gif),
        // тут тоже много чего ...
    ]);
```

Вроде бы ничего сложного валидировали, добавили фото в aws, открыли публичный доступ и создали элемент в БД.
Но проблема в том что как удалить эти картинки из aws если мы удалим свой элемент из БД.

Пример:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    ModelName::find($id)->delete();
    // И как тут удалить фото которое принадлежит этому элементу в aws?

    session()->flash('success', "Герой удален");

    return redirect()->route("anyroute");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел способ может кому еще поможет.

[Ссылка в документации](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#deleting-files)

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $hero = ModelName::find($id); // Находим элемент по id

    Storage::disk('s3')->delete('images/' . $hero->image); // Удаляем элемент из aws вот тут
    Storage::disk('s3')->delete('gif_images/' . $hero->gif_image); // И тут

    $hero->delete(); //Удаляем элемент из базы

    session()->flash('success', "Герой удален");

    return redirect()->route("anyroute");
}
```